# Why need bridging header even after using use_frameworks in pod file?

Tags: ios, swift, bridging-header

I am installing third party pod written in obj-C with use_frameworks in Swift. What I have read is that when we use use_framework, we do not need bridging header. But in my case I need to include an empty bridging header. Why is that?

Comment: use_framework is for library which is written in swift.

Comment: @Pushpa but i have used it with Objc library and it works. Only thing is that i need to include an empty header file.